# TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Tags: javascript, react-native, typeerror, cross-platform, computer-science

I am developing a React Native application and attempting to implement navigation using the react-native-flux library. However, I am encountering a 'TypeError: undefined is not a function  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. ' error when trying to import and use the navigation-related libraries from react-native-flux.

This error prevents me from properly navigating between screens in my application. I have reviewed the documentation and followed the suggested import patterns, but the issue persists. I am using the latest version of react-native-flux and have checked for any conflicting dependencies. I am also using the Hermes JavaScript engine.

And this only happens when i try to import the 'react-native-flux' library otherwise the App runs fine

I would really like to understand the possible causes of this error and explore troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue as i have been stuck on this for a very long time.

This is actual error message:

```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
 * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running,                     
 stop it and restart it in the current project.
 * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't 
 called., js engine: hermes
```

This is the code for the App.js file:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeScreen';
import Login from './Login';
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import { Router, Stack, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
       <Stack key="root">
         <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" />
         <Scene key="signup" component={SignUp} title="SignUp" />
         <Scene key="welcome" component={WelcomeScreen} />
      </Stack>
  </Router>
  );
};
```

So Any Help would be apperciated.
Thanks.